# Alternative to Grails hidden id field in forms

Tags: security, grails

Currently, my Grails forms use a hidden id field and hidden version field for edits. This seems like a huge security risk since someone could edit a form they have access to and change the id to update a different record. The same could happen with the version by setting the version to version-1. My question is: what is the best practice for not exposing the ID (in an editable fashion) in the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this risk is mitigated by checking that the user has access to the object with the ID received from the browser, so even if they tamper with the ID, their attempt at subterfuge will fail, e.g.

```
class OrderController {

  def deleteOrder(Order order) {
    User loggedInUser = getCurrentUser()

    if (order.owner.id == loggedInUser.id) {
      // let them delete their order
    } else {
      // tell them to bugger off
    }
  }
}
```

You could also encrypt/hash the IDs, e.g. include the ID and hashed ID as hidden form fields, then check on the server side that the received ID matches the received hashed ID. This should ensure that they haven't tampered with the ID or it's hash.

However, this still doesn't prove that they have access to the object with this ID, so strictly speaking you still need to a check like the above, which makes the encryption/hashing fairly pointless IMO.

In the case of the version field they can't do any harm by tampering with this. If they change the version to a different number, then (assuming you're checking for dirty writes), they'll get a notification that the data they submitted is out-of-date (even if it isn't).